# Handbrake CLI crop woes

Tags: math, video, html5-video

I love the Handbrake CLI and have been using it for an internal tool I created, to help convert big, uncompressed videos, into HTML5 ready MP4s.

This works REALLY well with your normal HD movies (1920x1080 / 1280x720), but not so well when you add a 720p video from YouTube, for instance, where the black bars have already been removed automatically by their encoder.

This means the input video has a resolution of 1280x528 (instead of 720 height, because it's missing black bars).

So, what I have to do for this to fit a preview panel I have, is scale the video to fit the height of the panel, then crop the excess width.

Basic logic, basic maths, yet Handbrake is distorting the whole thing and driving me insane.

Here's the line I'm using:

> ./HandBrakeCLI -i Man_of_Steel.mp4 -e x264 -a none -q 25 -f mp4 -o
>   test.mp4 --optimize -w 714 -l 402 --start-at duration:1 --stop-at duration:3 --crop 0:0:130:130

This saves a 3 second preview.

> The maths are:
>
> int scaledWidth;
>   int scaledHeight;
>
> int targetWidth = 714;
>
> int targetHeight = 402;
>
> float scaleFactor = (float) targetHeight / videoHeight; // scale to fit height
>
> scaledWidth  = (float)videoWidth * scaleFactor; // comes out as 974
>
> scaledHeight = (float)videoHeight * scaleFactor; // comes out as 402
>
> int offset = (scaledWidth - targetWidth); // comes out as 130px that
>   needs to be cropped on each side

However, the video comes out distorted!
Through trial and error, I figured out the right offset to make it look good is **169**, only I have no idea why that's the right value.

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers suggest that the `offset` applies to the *original* video, i.e. it is first moved and then scaled. Furthermore, you have to divide by two, because you want the whole margin to be spaced evenly on both sides.

```
int offset = (scaledWidth - targetWidth)/(2 * scaleFactor)
     170   = (    974     -     714    )/(2 * (402 / 528))
```

Comment: I did have it dividing by 2, but the distortion was even bigger! That worked freaking perfectly. I'm rubbish at maths, so don't get why you have to divide the 2 by the scale factor :x Thanks a bunch though!

Comment: @Andre: why you have to divide has little to do with math, and much to do with how your application handles its parameters. Particularly in what order it performs its various transformations.